# An object near the speed of light is moving slow and therefore not close to the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity

If I in my reference frame observe an object near the speed of light I can calculate the lorentzfactor which tells how slow the objects clock is going. Is it's velocity then slower? Say its reference frame is given by $S´$ and mine is given by $S$. Then from my perspective its time $t´=\gamma t$, if $x=x´=0$. Then its placement is given by $x=\gamma t v$? So actually $\frac{1}{\gamma} v = v´$?

Comment: Any object has a velocity of zero in its own reference frame.

Comment: I know but i'm talking about an "observed" velocity, which seems slower.

Comment: If S' is moving at v relative to S, then S is moving at -v relative to S'. I'm not quite sure what your confusion is, but don't forget that along with time dilation there is also length contraction

Comment: I think the confusion is that OP thinks time dilation causes the object to appear to  move slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition two the (by now) two excellent answers, let's consider that what you assume (time dilation causes an object to move slower) were true.

Let's assume the object $A$ to be in an inertial frame of reference $S'$ which has (relative to our "stationary" frame $S$) a velocity $v$ (thus, the object can be said to be moving with velocity $v$ relative to us).

If the velocity of $A$ *were* to appear slower in $S$ (as you assumed), then once again one could calculate time dilation (using the already dilated time as basis) and again would find that the object actually is moving slower. Doing this infinitely often times, our measurement of the velocity would eventually give $v \approx 0$.

Of course, this does not make sense, but it might show that your assumption cannot be true. **Time dilation only means that clocks in $S'$ are running slower as seen from $S$** (as explained in the other answers). Time dilation does *not* affect the velocity of $S'$.

Comment: Thank you very much! All the answers are very well explaned!

Comment: Yes you explained very well that the assumption is wrong. But why it is...? I mean at the speed of light A will be freezed, stop moving? Which somehow concludes that time dilation may affects the motion.

Comment: @SwayamJha I think this is very well explained in gandalf61's answer - mine was only meant as a sort of addition to show why the statement in the question cannot be true.

Answer (score 3):

The time dilation equation $t' = \gamma t$ means that when one second passes in your reference frame then you observe $\gamma < 1$ seconds pass in the reference frame of the moving object. But one second has still passed in your reference frame, and the equation of motion of the moving object in your reference frame is still $x(t)=vt$.

Comment: Cool. So that would mean that an object which moves with $v=0.9999c$ isn't appearing to be moving slow because then $v\neq0.9999c$ right? How can it be that an accelerating object approaching the speed if light ex. near a black hole, that it appears to freeze then and then isn't approaching the speed of light?

Answer (score 2):

> i can calculate the lorentzfactor which tells how slow the objects clock is going. Is it's velocity then slower?

No.

> Then from my perspective its time $t´=\gamma t$, if $x=x´=0$. Then its placement is given by $x=\gamma t v$? So actually $\frac{1}{\gamma} v = v´$?

No. Its velocity in your frame has nothing to do with the rate of its clock in your frame.