# Do time dilation affects motion?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, relative-motion

I know it doesn't but why not? Imagine when time dilation becomes Infinite then everything will stop or not? What will happen to a ball which hypothetically move at the speed of light so that space and time becomes 0 and 0. So in short, do time dilation affects the motion of an object?

Edit:- At the speed of light "internal" motion would be freezed not the external but this doesn't defies a robust physical parameter. How do Physics distinguish internal freeze but externally moving. Velocity is velocity! Thus, if internally object freezes it must externally too!

Comment: What exactlly do you mean by "affects motion"? It is indeed true that if you observe some frame of reference moving close to $c$, all motion in this frame will be slower from your reference frame. Also, FWIW, it does not really make sense to talk about massive objects moving at $c$, but only what happens if their velocity _approaches_ $c$.

Comment: Yeah from my perspective all motions "inside" the moving frame will be slower but will the velocity "of" the frame will slowed down?

Comment: This appears to be answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607728/)

Comment: Nope the answer explained that the assumption may be wrong but didn't took into account the fact that at the speed of light when time stops, what would happen to the motion of the moving object!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An object near the speed of light is moving slow and therefore not close to the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607728/an-object-near-the-speed-of-light-is-moving-slow-and-therefore-not-close-to-the)

Comment: It is impossible for a massive object to be at the speed of light. So there is no need to cover that case. It is non-physical

Comment: @Dale But I think it's just an excuse to escape the problem. If we don't analyze every situation how would we understand what time really is? We have to increase our domain no matter if it's hypothetical.

Comment: That is frankly a pretty absurd comment. We have a theory which predicts that x happens and that y is impossible. So a question about how y affects x is self-contradictory nonsense. The question assumes the theory because it is about x and the question rejects the theory because it assumes y is possible. So such a question rests on self contradictory premises. It cannot be answered by any other means than pointing out the self contradiction. It isn’t a desire to “escape” the question but a recognition that even questions and hypotheticals must be logically self consistent and this one is not.

Answer (score 1):

> do time dilation affects the motion of an object?

It does, but not in the way that you think. When an electron is accelerated, the nearer its velocity gets to the speed of light, the more energy is needed to make a small increase in the electron's velocity so that as the velocity tends to $c$, this energy tends to infinity. In other words, when you want to *dilate* time for an object you need to consume more energy.

However, contrary to what you think, when you provide specific energy to dilate time for a moving object, the object gets, say, specific linear velocity, and it will not miss this velocity anymore until you, by consuming additional energy,  exert some force to deccelerate it.

Comment: But when time dilation becomes Infinite the object will stop without a deaccelerating force! How?

Comment: @SwayamJha Infinite time dilation would freeze everything *inside* the object, rather than outside it. Remember that the linear velocity of the object is something determined by the *traveled distance*, which is an *outside* quantity, divided by the time measured by an *outside* observer.

Comment: Please see my edit. But, linea velocity is also equals to inside distance divided by inside time.

Comment: Good answer! I would only comment that in your last paragraph you mention consuming additional energy to decelerate it, but for deceleration the force is in the opposite direction of the velocity so you consume negative energy, I.e. you extract energy

Comment: @Dale Thank God that you finally upvoted one of my Qs/As! ;)

Comment: I have done it before, and will do it again. You needn’t act surprised. I actually don’t downvote you as much as you think I do. I just comment more than most downvoters, so to you I am the visible one

Answer (score 0):

Distance can only have zero length from the point of view of someone  travelling with a light wave.
If you are standing still , a clock moving past you close to the speed of light would have nearly zero seconds showing on it compared to a clock standing still in your hand. But no clock that can be put on a scale and weighed can ever reach the speed of light because Einstein's special relativity theory tell us that an infinite force would be required to get the clock to the speed of light and there isn't enough energy in the entire universe to create an infinite force on the clock !

Comment: You didn't explained how it will affects motion "of" the moving frame.

Comment: Time will pass slower in the  moving frame compared to the  still frame.So for example 1 second in the still frame will be 0.999 seconds in the moving frame. But someone in the moving frame will think that his time is 1 second and the other time is 0.999 seconds Both points of view are correct in special relativity!